# Where is this image of Darth Vader from?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, darth-vader

[image: kneeling Vader]

He kind of looks CGI and I'm pretty sure this isn't from any scene in the main films. Does anyone know where the picture came from and what Vader is doing here?

Comment: TinEye and Google Image Search are good ways to resolve questions like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this exact scene is from the *Force Unleashed 2* TV commercial "Snow" in which Vader confronts Starkiller in a snowy forest (at 0:17):

Answer (score 8):

This is a production still image for the game "[Force Unleashed 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Unleashed_II)".

It was produced by an artist called [Jason Martin](http://www.believerdeceiver.com/journal/2010/6/12/the-force-unleashed-2.html)

> *"Having the chance to model Darth Vader was an absolute child dream
>   come true!  Congrats to everyone who worked on this, your talent
>   consistently blows me away! The hard work and dedication really makes
>   this shine! Ill post some character sample stills once Im allowed to."*

[image]

You can see a wide selection of his still images from the game [here](http://www.zbrushcentral.com/showthread.php?101671-Jason-Martin-2010-production-work)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Happen to know when the scene happens/what he's doing?

Comment: @RedCaio - These are visual models produced using ZBrush. The wireframe models themselves appear in the game (in the cut scenes), but not in nearly as high quality. These are basically vanity shots produced for the studio.

Comment: Oh the hopes I had for this game...

Answer (score -3):

It's from The Force Unleashed 2.

Comment: This answer adds nothing to those already provided. If you have noting new to add, please refrain from answering.